# Is this a wireshark bug when display information about AMQP?

Tags: wireshark, amqp, spring-amqp

I am using `spring-amqp` and testing `RabbitListener`#`AcknowledgeMode`.

When i set `RabbitListener`#`AcknowledgeMode`#`AUTO`,I triggered the nack reponse by thorwing a exception in my `RabbitListener`.

When i set `defaultRequeueRejected` to `true`(it means message will requeue), package by wireshark:
[image]

**It looks like the last two bits represent these two properties.**

And When i set `defaultRequeueRejected` to `false`(it means message will not requeue), package by wireshark:
[image]

`Requeue` should be `false`.So is this a wireshark bug? Or do I understand something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a wireshark bug to me `0x03` Vs. `0x01`.

I just looked at the code in the client lib and the multiple bit is the LSB and the requeued bit is the next bit.

Comment: The `hf_amqp_method_basic_nack_requeue` is incorrectly declared with a mask of 0x01 instead of 0x02.  See https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/dissectors/packet-amqp.c;h=45940216962e4fa5fffe88ca852fa12d6381bc2c;hb=HEAD#l12806.  Please file a Wireshark bug report so it can be fixed.  Bugs are filed at: https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/.  Please attach a small packet capture file depicting the problem so it's easier for the developers to test and verify, or submit a patch yourself if you like, see: https://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/SubmittingPatches

Comment: I'm a little confused. Did they fix it correctly? https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16338     https://code.wireshark.org/review/35846

Comment: It looks like they changed the wrong mask; the mask for `multiple` should be 0x01 and `requeue` 0x02.